# sequelize does not create database on local machine

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am running:

```
sequelize db:migrate
```

on my local machine and it outputs:

```
Sequelize CLI [Node: 15.10.0, CLI: 6.2.0, ORM: 5.8.6]

Loaded configuration file "src/db/db.config.js".
Using environment "development".
```

but no migration takes place on my local machine. The same code and command migrate the DB normally on a Google cloud instance. How do I debug this problem? My device is Macbook Pro running macOs High Sierra 10.13.6.

Note: the database is already created. Even when I try to delete the DB and run `sequelize db:create`, still nothing happens.

Comment: sequlieze is not create db automaticaly

Comment: https://github.com/nkhs/node-sequelize check this project

Comment: Please how did you solve this? I am facing this same issue right now

Comment: oh true! .. This is it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62332722/problem-with-sequelize-dbmigrate-and-postgres